# How to quit a non-login shell?

Tags: ssh, shell, login, process

e.g. I use `ssh` to login into a Linux server with `zsh`. Then in the `zsh`, I type `zsh` to get a non-login shell. How can I quit the non-login `zsh` and get back to the login `zsh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exit
```

That will only exit the most recent shell, not 
the remote server, unless you're in the login shell.

You can see if you're in a login shell by echoing `$SHLVL`.  It will have value `1` if you're in your login shell but will be `2` when you start a subsequent shell.

The variable `$0` might also be set to `-zsh` in the login shell but `zsh` in others.

Comment: I find that `exit` can quit a login-shell as well.